# ParseBroadcastReceiver on Android causes my application to crash when the device is rebooted

Tags: android, parse-platform, crash

I have an Android application that is using Parse.  Generally everything works as expected.  I have followed all the instructions and tutorials and all is well with my application.  I receive notifications and my app handles them well.

The only issue I am seeing is that when my Galaxy S6 running the application is restarted I get the start "Application  has stopped".

Now, at this point, my application isn't even running.  I was able to narrow down the issue to the ParseBroadcastReceiver:

```html
     <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

This makes sense as this receiver has an intent filter for BOOT_COMPLETED, which means this receiver runs when the device is booted.  Commenting out this receiver eliminates the problem.

Has anyone seen or solved this problem?

Comment: Please put exact error details for getting a proper solution.

Comment: I cannot get anything meaningful in a logcat.  I restart the device, dump logcat to a file, but there is nothing in there that relates to my application.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my english but i will do my best helping you.

You have to create a new class which extends Application, without layout, just a java class.

My class looks like this:

```
public class Init extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, "applicationID", "clientKey");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

}
```

And you have to declare on your manifest like:

```
 <application
    android:name="your_package.class_which_initialize_service">
  <!--All your things of your manifest here-->
 </application>
```

As child of manifest root. (Many times just adding

android:name="your_package.class_which_initialize_service"

is enough

I hope that this help you and sorry again for my bad english :P

EDIT: Yes, commenting this line fix the problem but the services won't initializes automatically. Just launching your app manually.
I forgot to say that the sentence which initialize service cannot be duplicated, you have to delete this line from the class before, and copy to the class I wrote

Comment: This is not my problem.  I have extended Application and I initialize Parse as you have demonstrated.  The app works just fine.  It just stops when the phone is restarted.  It shouldn't even be running, but the BOOT_RECEIVER is causing the problem.  For now I have removed the "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" action, which makes the app stop crashing on device restart, but it is not ideal.

Comment: if you delete the BOOT_RECEIVER the parse service won't start at boot complete, then you won't receive any push until you start your app manually. If you restart your phone with the usb plug, Android Studio will show log and error of this crash without launch the app, I think that log will show "parse have be initialized before use". Try reboot your phone pluged and read the log. I hope this help you my friend